# Treegrid how use local json(memory proxy)

Tags: extjs4

My code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('Unit', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'task',type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'Unit',
        data:result,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
     var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        id:"treepanel",
        title: 'Core Team Projects',
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        collapsible: true,
        useArrows: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        singleExpand: true,
        //the 'columns' property is now 'headers'
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
            text: 'Task',
            flex: 2,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'task'
        },{
            //we must use the templateheader component so we can use a custom tpl
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'Duration',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'duration',
            align: 'center'
        }]
    });
});
```

JSON is: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.json

The tree don't display my result, how to do it? I am a new ExtJs4.

Sorry I don't want to use AJAX for get result.

Answer (score 0):

If json file is not on the same domain you need to use type: 'jsonp'

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link. You can get clear idea about client proxy in Ext JS.

http://www.pointerunits.com/2013/01/ext-js4-client-proxies.html

If your data is present in your server, you have to use any one server proxies for loading data from server.

Ajax proxy - For loading data by using AJAX call 
  JSONP proxy - For loading data from different server (for avoiding CORS Problem) 
  Rest Proxy - For loading data by calling rest services.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` attribute has to be declared inside the proxy:

Before ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x6/)):

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Unit',
    data: result,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

After: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh7x6/1/)):

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Unit',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        data: result,
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

Voilá!